# Add objects in an ArrayList through constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I am a beginner, and I am building a classical NimGame. Before, I used to save the project using an array. Now, I modify it to apply the `ArrayList` to this time. It seems no problem, though, the functions I've made are not working without any errors. I couldn't figure out why.

For now, I tried to add the `NimPlayer` type into the new `playerList`, which is the ArrayList. I put the ArrayList in the `NimModel`, and use the constructor from the `NimPlayer` to create new players. The `Nimsys` is the main panel to give commands and receive user inputs. That's why I separate them into three classes.

The command is like this
`$addplayer userName,familyName,givenName`. And the scanner should process the string and go through the constructor to be a new object.

Any help is highly appreciated, and thank you for your kindness and patience.

Here is my related code `Nimsys`:

```
public class Nimsys {

private NimModel nimModel;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Nimsys nimsys = new Nimsys();
    nimsys.processCommands();
}

private void processCommands() {
    this.nimModel = new NimModel();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to Nim\n");
    while (true) {
        System.out.print('$');
        String commandin = in.nextLine().trim();

        if (commandin.equalsIgnoreCase("addplayer")) {
            addplayer(in);
        }
        if (commandin.equalsIgnoreCase("removeplayer")) {
            removeplayer(in);
        }

}

private String[] splitName(String inName) {
    String[] splittedLine = inName.split(",");
    String[] name = null;
    if (splittedLine.length == 3) {
        String userName = splittedLine[0].trim();
        String familyName = splittedLine[1].trim();
        String givenName = splittedLine[2].trim();
        name = new String[3];
        name[0] = userName;
        name[1] = familyName;
        name[2] = givenName;
    }
    return name;
}
private void addplayer(Scanner in) {
    String inName = in.nextLine().trim();
    String[] name = splitName(inName);

    if (name != null && name.length == 3) {
        ArrayList<NimPlayer> playerList = nimModel.getPlayerList();
        for (NimPlayer player: playerList) {
            if (player.getUserName().contains(name[0])) {
                System.out.println("The player already exists.");
                return;
            } else {
                nimModel.createPlayer(name[0], name[1], name[2]);
                System.out.println("The player has been created.");
            }
        }        
    } 
private void removeplayer(Scanner in) {
    String removeUserName = in.nextLine().trim();
    NimPlayer player = nimModel.removePlayer(removeUserName);
    if (player == null) {
        System.out.println("The player does not exist");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Player " + player.getUserName() + 
                " removed successfully!");
    }
}
```

And the `NimModel`:

```
public class NimModel {

private NimPlayer nimplayer;

private ArrayList<NimPlayer> playerList = new ArrayList<>();

public void createPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {
    NimPlayer player = new NimPlayer(userName, familyName, givenName);
    playerList.add(player);     

}

public ArrayList<NimPlayer> getPlayerList() {
    return playerList;
}
public NimPlayer removePlayer(String userName) {
    for (NimPlayer player: playerList) {
        String nameCheck = nimplayer.getUserName();
        String playerName = player.getUserName();
        if (playerName.equals(nameCheck)) {
            playerList.remove(player);
            break;
        } 
    }
    return null;
```

Lastly, `NimPlayer` class

```
public class NimPlayer {


private final String userName;
private String familyName;
private String givenName;

private int gamesPlayed;
private int gamesWon;
private int winRatio;



public NimPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {

    this.userName = userName;
    this.familyName = familyName;
    this.givenName = givenName;
    this.gamesPlayed = 0;
    this.gamesWon = 0;
}
//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Are there some lines missing from your posted code or is your `addPlayer(Scanner in)` method defined within your `processCommands()` method?  This won't work.  Secondly, for cleanliness, since your `playerList` is within `NimModel`, you should move any code to do with iterating over that list to within `NimModel`.

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my code. What should I do with the `addplayer(Scanner in)`? It should take user input, though. I'll move those code related to iteration of `playerList`@codebod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use scanner.nextLine() you are asking for a new input to the user. So if you want the format: **$addplayer user,firstName,lastName** you have to fetch it into a string and use this string:

```
while (true) {
        System.out.print('$');
        String commandin = in.nextLine().trim();

        if (commandin.split(" ")[0].equalsIgnoreCase("addplayer")) {
            addplayer(commandin);
        }
    }
}

private void addplayer(String commandin) {
    String inName = commandin.split(" ")[1];
    String[] name = splitName(inName);
      ....
```

Comment: Thanks again! Have a nice day @Alex

Answer (score 1):

in a nutschell:

```
private void addplayer(Scanner in) {
String inName = in.nextLine().trim();
String[] name = splitName(inName);
if (name != null && name.length == 3) {
    ArrayList<NimPlayer> playerList = nimModel.getPlayerList();
    for (NimPlayer player: playerList) {
        if (player.getUserName().contains(name[0])) {
            System.out.println("The player already exists.");
            return;
        }
    }
    nimModel.createPlayer(name[0], name[1], name[2]);
    System.out.println("The player has been created.");         
}
```

Furthermore, your addPlayer() given in Nimsys is defined in your While(true) but I think it's more a typing error.
Personally I would also give a constructor to your model:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NimModel {

private NimPlayer nimplayer;

private ArrayList<NimPlayer> playerList;
public NimModel()
{
   this.playerList =  new ArrayList<NimPlayer>();
}
public void createPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {
    NimPlayer player = new NimPlayer(userName, familyName, givenName);
    playerList.add(player);

}

public ArrayList<NimPlayer> getPlayerList() {
    return playerList;
}

public NimPlayer removePlayer(String userName) {
    for (NimPlayer player : playerList) {
        String nameCheck = nimplayer.getUserName();
        String playerName = player.getUserName();
        if (playerName.equals(nameCheck)) {
            playerList.remove(player);
            break;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my code. I've spotted the tying error and edited the post. My question now turns to that it seems the scanner doesn't take the user input at the same time. `$addplayer user,firstName,lastName` doesn't work in the `processCommand`.